# Iterating over a list in groups of two or more

Tags: flutter, dart

I like to iterate over a list and split them up in couples like this:

```
List<String> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
List<Tuple2> listOfTuples = list.take2((value1,value2) => Tuple2(value1,value2));
print(listOfTuples.toString()); // output => [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

I know there is a `take(count)` in dart but I did not find a good example.

I know I can do it with a `for` loop etc. but I am wondering if there us a more elegant way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing built in. The way I'd write this today is:

```
  var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  var tuples = [
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i += 2) Tuple2(list[i], list[i + 1]),
  ];
```

You *could* write an extension that gives an api `take2` on `List` that could be used in the way you describe.

```
extension Take2<T> on List<T> {
  List<R> take2<R>(R Function(T, T) transform) => [
        for (int i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i += 2)
          transform(this[i], this[i + 1]),
      ];
}
```

Comment: Can no wait for 2.6 in stable flutter